# Is there a CocoaPods JSON API?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Is there a way to get a pod specification (versions, name, date etc.) via an API? The closest thing I've found is the search request from their site but not a JSON API.

If you look at cocoacontrols there has to be something like an API because they find the correct pod to your repo.

Background: I need to look up a pod and see if there is a new version available.

I looked into the GitHub Repo but couldn't find the required specs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the only parts of the CocoaPods system is the command line tool and the [specs repo](https://github.com/cocoapods/specs). I can think of a few ways you could do this but they would definitely be more involved than a provided API.

You could use Github's API to query the specs repo. The folder structure for each spec is the same so you would look at `repo/specname` to see the available version numbers in the form of folders.

If you wanted to do it locally you could do something similar with the folder in `~/.cocoapods/master` which is a clone of the specs repo.

Comment: I've upvoted Keiths because it is the *right* answer, we do however have an unofficial a.k.a it can change when we need it, URL scheme for a podspec's information : http://cocoapods.org/api/v1/pod/ARAnalytics.json

Answer (score 4):

[Actually they have API](http://metrics.cocoapods.org/api/v1/pods/SidebarOverlay).

I know that this question is too old, but anyway it places on first place in Google. So, at least another people will know that CocoaPods provides API.

Comment: Metrics API doesn't list available pod versions

Answer (score 1):

Technically, kinda -- see https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.7.2/ and https://github.com/CocoaPods/cdn.cocoapods.org

The [Specs](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) follow a 'lookup pattern' wherein the case sensitive pod name is md5 hashed, a prefix is generated from the hex digest, and a path is generated. Here is how it looks in python:

```py
In [2]: api = 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org'
   ...: podname = 'FirebaseDynamicLinks'
   ...: version = '10.13.0'

In [3]: hash = yaml.safe_load(requests.get(f"{api}/CocoaPods-version.yml").text)
   ...:
   ...: prefix_lengths = hash['prefix_lengths']
   ...: prefix_lengths
Out[3]: [1, 1, 1]

In [4]: hashed = hashlib.md5(podname.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
   ...: hashed
Out[4]: '6e53dba4b40e400f2f7e3dab02b2c2b2'

In [5]: r = [hashed[i:i+length] for i, length in enumerate(prefix_lengths)]
   ...: r.extend([podname, version, f"{podname}.podspec.json"])
   ...: r
Out[5]:
['6',
 'e',
 '5',
 'FirebaseDynamicLinks',
 '10.13.0',
 'FirebaseDynamicLinks.podspec.json']

In [6]: spec = requests.get(f"{api}/Specs/{'/'.join(r)}").json()
   ...: spec['description']
Out[6]: 'Firebase Dynamic Links are deep links that enhance user experience and increase engagement by retaining context post-install, across platforms.'
```

I, personally, am annoyed at the mixing of yaml and json. One can, seemingly, assume it is the first three digits are what matter if you don't mind it breaking possibly.

You may also find *all* pods via `/all_pods.txt` and all versions for a given pod via `"/all_pods_versions_{}_{}_{}.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe Cocoapods works by directly inspecting the [podspecs GitHub repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs). You can also [customize](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#pod) it to look at a custom spec repo of your choosing (e.g. for pods internal to a company), but there's no API for listing pods.